# PRTG custom script returns valid XML but dashboard complains

Tags: xml, prtg

I have a PRTG custom script in the EXEXML directory which has been configured within the PRTG dashboard.

When I run it manually, I get the following output which, as far as I'm aware, is perfectly valid:

```
<prtg>
  <result>
    <channel>MaxCPUWL1</channel>
    <value>113</value>
  </result>
  <text>OK</text>
</prtg>
```

In fact, I have *another* script which pretty much generates the same format, including identical `CR/LF` sequences at the end of the lines:

```
<prtg>
  <result>
    <channel>Item age</channel>
    <value>14</value>
  </result>
  <text>April 15, 2015</text>
</prtg>
```

I've even checked in detail the output of both to ensure I haven't done something stupid, like use `channe1` (with a one) instead of `channel` (with an `L`).

And yet, with the first one, I keep getting in the dashboard:

> XML: The returned xml does not match the expected schema. (code: PE233) -- JSON: The returned json does not match the expected structure (Invalid JSON.). (code: PE231)

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the properties of the sensor, you can capture the output of the executable under certain conditions:

```
o Discard EXE result
o Write EXE result to disk
o Write EXE result to disk in case of error
```

A good way to see what your custom sensor is doing is to set that middle option (normally the first is set) and then go and look for the file `Result of Sensor XXXX.txt` (where `XXXX` is the sensor ID) in the sensor logs directory, such as:

```
C:\ProgramData\Paessler\PRTG Network Monitor\Logs (Sensors)
```

That should show you any errors that are occurring in the script, or at least the output that is confusing the PRTG sensor output analysis.

In this *particular* case, it was having trouble running the `pscp` command to go out and retrieve a file from a remote server, but this approach should hopefully be able to evaluate and fix a wide variety of problems.

Comment: Just to emphasize, look for the Logs directory in *C:/ProgramData*, not under the PRTG install directory. In my case PRTG was unable to run my powershell script even though I set the execution policy to Unrestricted - because I did it for the x64 Powershell but PRTG runs the x86 shell. So if that's your problem, make sure you run Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted in the x86 shell.